# Is this explicit linking against OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX still necessary with this CMake linking command?

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, openmp

I am using CMake and GNU's parallel algorithms and the following code snippet in my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
if (OPENMP_FOUND)
    set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_C_FLAGS}")
    set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
    set (CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}")
endif().
```

Does that make the following command redundant?

```
target_link_libraries(MyTarget OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX)?
```

I have tried to find the answer [here](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/cspec20.pdf) but to no avail. Upon printing the output of the above variables using the `message` command, I see that the last two are empty.

```
-- OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS are: -fopenmp
-- OpenMP_C_FLAGS are: -Xclang -fopenmp 
-- CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS are:  
-- OpenMP_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS are:
```

I tried looking up the variable definition [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/variable/CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS.html) but did not find out anything more. A small test programme using:

```
__gnu_parallel::for_each
```

ran in parallel regardless whether I included:

```
target_link_libraries(MyTarget OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX)
```

which leads me to conclude that it is not necessary. Is that true?

My `gcc` is `g++-9 (Homebrew GCC 9.3.0_1) 9.3.0.`

Comment: The latter form using `OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX` is almost certainly preferred.  Is there a reason you're considering the former?

Comment: I have no good reason to use the former (if ...) snippet, no. If you write this up as the answer, then I shall accept it. Is the setting of flags in the multiline command outdated/more error-prone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the code:

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
```

will update your C++ compile flags with the proper `-fopenmp` option, this is an old antiquated approach.

By linking against the provided imported target `OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX`, you achieve the same effect because this target provides the `-fopenmp` compile option in its `INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS` property. Likewise, this imported target propagates any dependent OpenMP libraries you may need (depending on the language), which would otherwise require an additional manual step of linking to `${OpenMP_CXX_LIBRARIES}`. So, linking directly to the imported target `OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX` should be the preferred approach; it saves you the extra manual steps and adheres to modern CMake axioms:

```
target_link_libraries(MyTarget PRIVATE OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX)
```

Note, the official documentation for the CMake OpenMP Find Module, and the variables/targets it provides, is [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/module/FindOpenMP.html).